# Counting total number or things that happen each hour in sql

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a list of roughly 3000 rows. Each row has a different end time. see below

```
Fund name | Fund ID   | RedeemTime  | PurchaseTime | LatestTime  |
__________  _________  ____________   ____________ | ___________ |
Title1    | IDnumber  |  4:00:00    | 14:30:00     |  14:30:00   |
Title2    | IDnumber2 | 13:30:00    | 12:00:00     |  13:30:00   |
Title3    | IDnumber3 | 10:00:00    | 14:00:00     |  14:00:00   |
Title4    | IDnumber4 | 10:00:00    | 10:30:00     |  10:30:00   |
```

I am currently using a case statement for the 5th column to find the later of the two times.

I need to take the 5th column and provide a count of what happens each hour. For example on the table above the results would be

```
Hour     |  Count
_________ _______
10:00:00 |    1
13:00:00 |    1
14:00:00 |    2
```

Comment: Are the times stored as datetimes?  Is there a date component or is everything within one day?

Comment: Can you add sample results? What constitutes "happen[ing] between each hour"?  Is that a start or an overlap?

Comment: they are stored as datetimes. while there is a date component it is irrelevant. meaning, the dates or back 200 years ago. all that is important is the actual time

Comment: happening constitutes between the hour of the day. for example on the above, between 1pm-2pm would have a count of 1, and between 2pm-3pm would also have a count of 1

Comment: . . That suggests based on start time, rather than elapsed time.  The count for 1 p.m. is 0, right?

Comment: i have edited the table (and a hopeful results table) to be more clear on what i'm looking for. i apologize for the vagueness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could "normalize" the two times in a subquery.  You can generate a list of hours using a CTE. For example, for all hours in August 2012:

```
; with  HourList as
        (
        select  cast('2012-08-01' as datetime) as DateCol
        union all
        select  dateadd(hour, 1, DateCol)
        from    HourList
        where   dateadd(hour, 1, DateCol) < '2012-09-01'
        )
select  hr.DateCol
,       count(yt.StartTime)
from    HourList hr
left join
        (
        select  case when time1 > time2 then time1 else time2 end as EndTime
        from    YourTable
        ) yt
on      yt.EndTime <= hr.DateCol and hr.DateCol < dateadd(hour, 1, yt.EndTime)
group by
        hr.DateCol
option  (maxrecursion 0)
```

If you don't have a table filled with hours, there are ways to generate it.  They all depend on your database.  So if you'd like help with that, post which database you are using.

Comment: sql server 2008 r2. it would be great to get help with the count statement. that is really giving me a hard time

Comment: Ok, added CTE for SQL Server 2008.  The count was already there. If something isn't working, explain!

Comment: @Andomar . . . I like your solution, but check out the comments.  It seems like the question is about starts, not elapsed time.

Comment: @Andomar I have edited the tables above to be more clear on my end goal

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Ok, edited in answer to just count the rows in the hour of their maximum date

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using only a time field...

First, select which time is greater:

```
(CASE WHEN time2 > time1 THEN time2
ELSE time1) as time
```

Then you would `SELECT` a `COUNT` with `GROUP BY HOUR(time)`